# Cx_Freeze 5.0.1 + Python3.4 virtualenv error

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, cx-freeze

I have been trying to figure out what the following error means but unfortunately I am not being able to handle it. The complete traceback resulting from the execution of the generated executable is:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
File "/home/prog3/Ambiente/p34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cx_Freeze-5.0.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>
__import__(name + "__init__")
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
File "/home/prog3/Ambiente/p34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cx_Freeze-5.0.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 24, in <module>
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "App.py", line 10, in <module>
File "/home/prog3/Ambiente/p34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/glymur/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from glymur import version
File "/home/prog3/Ambiente/p34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/glymur/version.py", line 15, in <module>
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
File "/home/prog3/Ambiente/p34/lib/python3.4/distutils/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
real_distutils = imp.load_module("_virtualenv_distutils", None, distutils_path, ('', '', imp.PKG_DIRECTORY))
File "/home/prog3/Ambiente/p34/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 245, in load_module
return load_package(name, filename)
File "/home/prog3/Ambiente/p34/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 217, in load_package
return methods.load()
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1219, in load
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

My setup.py file looks like:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includefiles = ['libopenjp2.so','libopenjp2.so.2.2.0','libopenjp2.so.7']
includes = []
excludes = ['Tkinter']
packages = ["os","sys","PyQt5.QtCore","PyQt5.QtGui","PyQt5.QtWidgets","numpy",  "subprocess","encodings","glymur","matplotlib","math","PIL","skimage","scipy","matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg","lxml","ctypes","re","collections","struct","contextlib","itertools","uuid","warnings"]
build_exe_options = {"packages":[],
        "excludes":["Tkinter"],"includefiles":['libopenjp2.so','libopenjp2.so.2.2.0','libopenjp2.so.7'],"includes":[],"copy_dependent_files":True
                }

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
  base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name='alignosis',
  version='0.1',
  description='Alignment of two differently stained whole-slide JPEG2000 digital pathology images',
  options = {'build_exe': {'includes':includes,'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
  executables= [Executable('App.py')])
```

I must say that once my virtualenv containing all the required packages is activated and after execution of the above setup.py by: 
`python setup.py build`,
 I get no errors and so it is created the build folder.

I am aware that probably I dont need to have a so big list of packages to include given that some of them are built-in and I am sorry for that...

I appreciate any suggestion/help that you can give to me.
Thank you

Comment: I had the same problem two days ago. When I came out of virtual environment, the binary/exe was running successfully!! I'm suspicious that `from distutils.version import LooseVersion` is the culprit. I've seen with multiple libraries. I still don't know what is the solution with virtual env. If you found a solution please do share :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In fact, I was unable to proceed using this approach. I used pyinstaller instead and everything worked.

Comment: oh good that it worked for you! I struggled using *pyinstaller*. If your `setup.py` is open sourced, can you point me there ?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Windows with Python 3.6.  I usually use a virtualenv, as I find it much cleaner and have a lot of dependencies for that program.  I'm afraid I will have to test without the virtual environment and see if it better works.  This seems to be due to one of the above dependencies, although I'm unaware of which (I will compare your list of packages with mine, but admittedly, cx_Freeze will freeze more packages that are mentioned in our lists, and the error message is quite unhelpful).