# Can't run exe created with cx-freeze

Tags: python, virtualenv, cx-freeze

I've been using [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to create an executable from a set of Python scripts. The `setup.py` looks like the following

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      description='some description',
      options={'build_exe': {'includes': ['numpy.core._methods',
                                          'numpy.lib.format',
                                          'matplotlib'],
                             'packages': ['matplotlib.backends.backend_agg']}},
      executables=[Executable('main.py', targetName="foo.exe")])
```

Then I invoke the build from the command line

```
python setup.py build
```

This succeeds and creates the executable along with the required dependencies. However when I try to run the application I see the following (paths have been modified to removed personal info)

```
> build\foo.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{long_path}\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "{long_path}\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "{root_path}\plot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "{long_path}\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    import distutils.version
  File "{long_path}\venv\lib\distutils\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    real_distutils = imp.load_module("_virtualenv_distutils", None, distutils_path, ('', '', imp.PKG_DIRECTORY))
  File "{long_path}\venv\lib\imp.py", line 245, in load_module
    return load_package(name, filename)
  File "{long_path}\venv\lib\imp.py", line 217, in load_package
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 692, in _load
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Is something incorrect in my `setup.py`? What can I do to correct the build of this application?

Versions:

```
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
cx-Freeze==5.1.1
```

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146196/cx-freeze-5-0-1-python3-4-virtualenv-error has the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug when using a combination of `cx-freeze`, `distutils` and `virtualenv` (see [here](https://gist.github.com/nicoddemus/ca0acd93a20acbc42d1d)).

From the above link:

> This problem happens because `distutils` does not install all its modules into the virtualenv, it only creates a package with some magic code in the `__init__` file to import its submodules dynamically. This is a problem to cx-freeze's static module analysis, which complains during the `build` command that it can't find distutils modules.

Solution (workaround) from the above link:

The workaround used was to tell `cx-freeze` to exclude `distutils` and add the package from the original interpreter (not from the `virtualenv`) manually.

```
# contents of setup.py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import distutils
import opcode
import os

# opcode is not a virtualenv module, so we can use it to find the stdlib; this is the same
# trick used by distutils itself it installs itself into the virtualenv
distutils_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(opcode.__file__), 'distutils')
build_exe_options = {'include_files': [(distutils_path, 'lib/distutils')],
                     'excludes': ['distutils']}

setup(
    name="foo",
    version="0.1",
    description="My app",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("foo_main.py", base=None)],
)
```